# How to alter CSS in an iframe in a frameset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

First: I do not have influence of the following HTML construct. What I have to do is to build a frame around it.
So I got a PHP file, and including the HTML file, which contains a frameset of three different frames. Just one of it got a name: "main".

How can I add a style tag not to the iframe HTML, but to the third inner frame HTML?

What I got:

In my outer frame, Im trying to add a .css-file, which works but only for the iframe-HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').load( function () {
        var $head = $("iframe").contents().find("head");                
        $head.append($("<link/>", 
            { rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/test.css", type: "text/css" 
}));
    });
});
```

Just to clear things up:
PHP OUTSIDE -> includes with an iframe -> HTML construct with frameset -> throu 3 -frames -> loads -> three different .html-files.

So I got:

```
<iframe>head&body
<frameset>
<frame>head&body</frame>
<frame>head&body</frame>
<frame name="main">head&body</frame>
</frameset>
</iframe>
```

And: It's all on one domain!

[image]
I have to add the test.css to the frame at the bottom of the picture.
Or change the existing .css-file also at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: Please post the HTML too.

Comment: Does the ifame content originate from your domain? if not you probably can't do much to it

Comment: try `$head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" type="text/css">');` and see if that works.

Comment: Do you have `<frame>`s or `<iframe>`s or both?

Comment: @Pete is correct, if you're attempting to inject like that, you're probably going to run into tons of cross-domain issues

Comment: its all on one domain!

Comment: @AntonyMN: thats literally the same I already got, and its working, but it appends to the first iframe head, so it doesnt relative to the style in the frameset...

Comment: In that case, instead of just referencing `$('iframe')`, you need to set the id of the target frame, and then set it as the the target element, `$('#My_ID").load()`

Comment: @AntonyMN: Well, I am not able to give it an ID, but I can try with the name "main"... or is it possible to just change the existing .css-file? The one at the bottom of the picture of the code?
I mean to edit the name to my test.css with javascript.

Comment: ok, I cant manage to append the .css to any "frame".
Just the iframe-head is being recognized... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, but this seems way outdated. Since "frameset"s and "frame"s are not supported in HTML5, I actually dont want a solution which wont work tomorrow.

Since the framesets are loaded from the first .htm-file, I'm gonna skip the default.htm and build a set of iframes which load the four different htm-files.

I already got it working, and the test.css-file also works like a charm.

Next advantage: Since I can name the iframes now, I can move them around just like I want. 
I think thats the best solution right here.

Thanks for your help anyway.